# Open circuit voltage

Tags: voltage

I'm not sure how I go about finding \$V_0\$ in this circuit. The current source just confuses things for me. \$R_1\$ = 10 kOhms and \$I_g\$ = 17 mA in this example.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Well, you know what the total resistances are in the series pairs. You know the total current. You can calculate the current through each pair, and thus the voltage across any one resistor.

Comment: Tip: If you reduce the whole network to a Thevanin equivalent resistance and a current source you can calculate the voltage across the current source, and all the rest can be done with simple Ohm's Law.

Answer (score 1):

**Converting current source into voltage source**

You could read this article.
If the current source confuses you, you could convert it into an equivalent voltage source using the following theory:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_transformation

**Then,**

The 2K ohm and 4K ohm resistors have zero current flowing through them (open circuit), and hence can be discarded in our voltage calculations. Since we need to find Vo, which is a potential difference, we can assume a reference node (top one) to be at 0V. Thus, the current division would be in the inverse ratio of the resistances in the parallel branches.

Hence, I1 = 15/(15+20) * 17 mA = 7.2857 mA.

Similarly, I2 = 20/(20+15) * 17 mA = 9.7142 mA.

Thus, Vo = I1 * 10 - I2*3 = 72.857 - 29.142 = 43.714 V.

This is your answer, and if you have any doubts, you could go through any of these articles:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_divider

Comment: Think yu got your units wrong there - they're KΩ, no Ω.

Comment: Not really. The mA * kohm -> Volt, is what I did.

Comment: Facepalm moment...- it was ME getting the units wrong...

Comment: Happens to the best of us, sir.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an easy way to go about it:

[image]

Comment: You have a sign error - the voltage in step 3 should be negative.